# What is the significance of a reduced residue system?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I know that a reduced residue system consists of elements from a complete residue system (of, say, $mod(n)$) which satisfy:

- $(a,n) = 1$ for each $a$ in the complete residue system
- A reduced residue system has $φ(n)$ elements

However, I don't understand the significance of articulating this. In what way is it useful? What possible information can we derive from an element's reduced residue system?

Comment: For instance, it can be used to prove the Euler's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Reducing it so that all elements are coprime to $n$ makes sure that all elements have an inverse (a multiplicative one, that is). Therefore, the system we work in is a (finite) group under $(\cdot)$, so we can do fun things with them like proving (as mentioned in the comments) that for each $a$ in that group we have

$$a^{\varphi(n)}=1$$

and for example, that the amount of generators in that group (provided there is one) is $\varphi(\varphi(n))$. In general, knowing that each element has a multiplicative inverse is very useful, and that is why we can do much more with those systems when $n$ is prime.